# For Memorial Day

Tags: mathematics, wordplay, visual, cipher, rebus

I was asked to bring something specific for our big Memorial Day Barbecue.

I was told to bring an item which is depicted by the following six pictures, though I'm guessing I shouldn't take things at face value.

1. 

[image: this]

2. 

[image: and this]

3. 

[image]

4. 

[image]

5. 

[image]

6. 

[image]

> > **Anyone know what they want me to bring?**

HINT #1:

> I'd like to point out that the men and women of a country's armed forces are people that their nation's citizens can count on.

HINT #2:

> Hint #1 is actually, really, a hint. Two hints, actually! Really!

HINT #3:

> Each of the pictures (except one, pointedly) have a number of ***things***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the pointy guy is the odd man out, right? In the other pics we have a number of circles.
3
(pointy guy)
1
4
1
5

3.1415

So, I get pi, which is the thing I'm bringing. (Apple Pie)

Comment: You got it! And...you asked it?

Comment: @Dan Russell  Uh, doy:[answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: No points received, none expected. Just letting the world know what my pie is all about.

Comment: Other options: offer a bounty to get the question more attention. Let it remain unanswered a bit longer. Go into chat and prod people to take a look. You never know when someone's working on your puzzle, and having the OP suddenly answer it can be frustrating.

Comment: Having [offered a bounty](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32762/good-apple-hunting), and understanding what it means, I've had but a few hits, so I did what I thought I should do. Is seven days not a considerate amount of time? Were you working on the puzzle and not giving me (partial or otherwise) answers?

Comment: You don't have to read answers if you want to figure it out yourself...

Comment: I think it's more a philosophical point. Puzzling is a different kind of SE site, where users challenge one another to solve puzzles. Some highly-rated questions like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18782/a-good-puzzle-is-a-double-edged-sword), [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/a-hunt-for-long-forgotten-treasure-but-beware-the-pirates-curse), and [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30523/fwd-re-karen-is-missing) took weeks to solve. I don't really see the value in anyone *ever* posting their own solution...where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> Cheese

Reason:

> 3 medals, 8 men, 5 (4 arms of the '+' and 'H'), C5 Galaxy, 10 to 2 = 10x2=20, 5 medals.  3,8,5,5,20,5 = Cheese

The point:

> American Cheese?

Update:

> The "Never forget" 10x2=20 would correspond to 't', not 's' as I claimed - oops.  That means there is a -1 involved (missing man?). Still puzzli g...

Comment: But you're missing the ***point***.  It's in the clues.

Comment: The "point" is an essential part of the [tag:math] equation.